# Targeting second child of li element in jQuery conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having an issue where I can't seem to target a `2nd` child of an `li` element and use it in a conditional statement. Do the jQuery conditionals not work with `li:nth-child(2)`?

```
if($(".steps ul li:first-child").attr('aria-selected') == "true") {
    $( ".steps ul li:first-child" ).append( "<div class='step-img'><img src='../images/step1.png' alt='Step 1'></div>" );
}
if(".steps ul li:nth-child(2)").hasClass(".current")) {
    $( ".steps ul li:nth-child(2)" ).append( "<div class='step-img'><img src='../images/step2.png' alt='Step 2'></div>" );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `$` selector and remove `.` from your selector:

```
if(".steps ul li:nth-child(2)").hasClass(".current"))
// ^ missing $ here                     //^--- Remove this dot
```

It should be

```
if($(".steps ul li:nth-child(2)").hasClass("current"))
```

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry, I must've copied and pasted it wrong.  It still doesn't seem to work.  Here is the HTML code in the 2nd child.

`<li role="tab" class="current" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true"><a id="create-rfq-t-1" href="#create-rfq-h-1" aria-controls="create-rfq-p-1"><span class="current-info audible">current step: </span><span class="number">2.</span> Payment Information</a></li>`

Comment: @RobertAllenBaker Can you make a fiddle please? I'll try to figure out problem.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is replace the text steps of JQuery Steps with an image of a progress bar.

Comment: @RobertAllenBaker In this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0oqu8ztu/), Its working, please check it.

Comment: @RobertAllenBaker [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t162z0et/3/) According to your jQuery selector, it will work only when `ul` is inside `.steps` but you don't have any such thing in `HTML`. Wrap your code in a `div` having class `steps` and wrap your JavaScript code inside `$(function() { ... });` so that it finds DOM elements when code runs.

Comment: That's strange, I added it, but it didnt' seem to update.

Comment: @Robert please check my fiddle, I have added all working code there

Comment: I tried to implement it but it still doesn't seem to work.  I did as you said, and even wrapped it in a document ready function...  You can see the output here: http://staging.delivermyride.com/create-rfq.php

Comment: @RobertAllenBaker you have errors in your console. All of them need to fix first.